# How to clear fragmentbackStack in android for specific conditions

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-stack

I have one activity in which I load all details of my application by loading different different fragment in my activity's frame-layout.

In case of simple flow, when I load A > B > C > D and then coming back in D > C >B >A is working fine as expected. I always want to move from B to A when back is pressed.

But now in one instance, I have different seq. in which I load A > B > C and then from C I have one button from which I need to load B again. Now when user press back on B, I need to go to A again without going to C. So to achieve that,in onKeyDown event of the parent activity, I checked that if the current fragment is my B fragment then just load A fragment and clear the backstack by popBackStackImmediate() (as I don't need it anymore). But now when I press back on B then it does load fragment A but the fragment B is not removed. I also tried to check for several answers for removing and adding fragments manually but still no luck. If you have any suggestions for that also then please explain me that process of add and remove or give me some reference site location where I can get details.

I tried to figure out the exact working of backstack but in that also, no luck. I don't understand what's going on (Why that fragment B is not removed and getting added to A). I have been trying for this from last two days. Please help me out.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Key down = " + keyCode);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                    RefillMainScreen.FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
                RefillMainScreen refillMainScreen = (RefillMainScreen)                                                                                                                           getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(RefillMainScreen.FRAGMENT_TAG);
                if (refillMainScreen.isVisible()) {
                      MainActivity.displayBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    while (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                    }
                    loadFragment(new DashboardFragment(), false);

                } else {
                    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                }
            } else {
                super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button Click where you wish to from C - A simply pop the back stack as

```
public void onClick(View v){
   fragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

This will pop C from the back stack i.e. take it out or remove and you will go back to B and since you would have added B to back stack while coming from A, on onBackPress from B you will be taken back to A, the way you want. :)

Comment: Hello Atul, This resolved my issue. But can you please tell me in detail that what exactly is done by popBackStack : Whether it will remove all fragments from backStack or simply it will just remove loaded fragment and then load first fragment in backstack ?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.  You did addToBackStack when moving from Fragment B to C, ryt? So doing popBackStack will just remove your C from the back stack since it is on top as of now.

Comment: I have one another question.In one specific seq.,I need to go from A > C and then on some button click of C,I need to go to B frag. and when back is pressed on B now,then A should be loaded.This is how I am impl it>>I loaded frag. A and then loaded C from it adding A to backstack. Now I loaded B on button click in C **without** adding C to backstack. So, now I press back on B then A should be loaded as only A is in backstack.But A is getting overlapped with B frag.I don't understand the reason.If I manually remove B then everything works fine but question is shouldn't back pressing remove it?

Comment: The definition of addToBackStack says - Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack. So if you are on Fragment A, you call fragment C from it and call addToBackStack() then its fragment C which will be added to the backstack. So dont add this and rest is fine. Let me know if you still have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to make sure I understood it, let me make it clear again that by adding "addtobackstack(null)" before committing a transaction is nothing to do with that particular fragment. It will just reverse the whole transaction when back is pressed. It's not the fragment which is imp., it is the transaction, right ? so in my previous case, when back was pressed, it reversed the transaction from  C > A but as B was not in the picture, it din't remove that frag and that's why it is shown as it is and gets overlapped. Right ?

Comment: so in my previous case, when back was pressed, it reversed the transaction from C > A -- you are right here. Can you explain more on - as B was not in the picture, it din't remove that frag and that's why it is shown as it is and gets overlapped. ??

Comment: MY Task: Load A>C, then C>B and then on back press, B>A. What I did was, I loaded C from A with addtobackstack(null). Now I loaded B from C without any backstack entry.Now, When I press back from B, it is going to A as expected but it is not removing that B. So, that was my question that, as the transaction from B >A was not added to backstack, B was not in the picture at all. So now, when I press back, it will reverse that transaction from A>C (which is C>A) ,so A will be loaded again, but B won't be removed as it has nothing to do with transaction. Have I got correct understanding ?

Comment: Sorry for the late replies.. :) I will try to be quick from next time.

Comment: Yes you got it correct. B was never in the picture since you didn't add it. Are you doing popBackStack() any where in between A > C > B?

Comment: Nope. Nowhere. Just replacing fragment with each other, No popbackstack().

Comment: can you explain me somewhat in detail for popBackStack also (if possible, with some example)? I guess I am still having issues in understanding that.

Comment: we should take it offline now. Mail me your contact detail on my email ID atul2504@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the method [addToBackStack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) when you are moving from C to B. This way, the transaction won't be remembered.